# callback function when navigation element has a class "active" jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [ScrollIt][1] plugin which automatically adds an "active" class on an navigation element and  makes it easy to create paginated, feature vertically scrolling pages.

I want to change the opacity of my navigation whenever the active class is not on an anchor element with the `href="#home"`.

But I don't know how to check if the currently active item is the element which don't have this `href="#home"` and if is not that to add the opacity.

**UPDATE WITH  WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

```
  function myCallBackFunction() {
    $('.navbar').css("opacity",this.is('[href="#home"]') ? 1 : 0);
    }
    var updateActive = function(ndx,myCallbackFunction) {
        if(settings.onPageChange && ndx && (active != ndx)) settings.onPageChange(ndx);

        active = ndx;
        $('[data-scroll-nav]').removeClass(settings.activeClass);
        $('[data-scroll-nav=' + ndx + ']').addClass(settings.activeClass);
        myCallbackFunction.call($('[data-scroll-nav=' + ndx + ']'));
    };
```

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined`

Any suggestions on how I might do this ?

Comment: change opacity from 1 to what? 0?

Comment: from 0 which is the actual  to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call you *callback*, you could use `.call()` liek that :

```
var updateActive = function(ndx, myCallbackFunction) {
    //the original code
    myCallbackFunction.call($('[data-scroll-nav=' + ndx + ']'));
}
```

Then in your function, you check `this`:

```
function myCallBackFunction() {
    $('.navbar').css("opacity",this.is('[href="#home"]') ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, and I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined ` I've editet my question with the exact code I've tried.

Comment: Remove `myCallBackFunction` from the argument `function(ndx){}`

Answer (score 0):

Try, if i understand behaviour you are looking for:

```
$('.navbar').css("opacity",$('[data-scroll-nav][href="#home"].active').length?0:1);
```

Comment: Tried with this also but is not working, please take a look again at my question, I've edited.